# How to save huge byte array into azure table storage?

Tags: c#, arrays, azure, large-files, azure-table-storage

I have tableEntity that contains `byte[]` property

```
[StorageTableName("TestTable")]
public class TestTableEntity : TableEntity
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

In this property I want to put some file converted into bytes (if it is incorrect - please suggest another solution).

```
var table = tableStorage.Table<TestTableEntity>();
await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var entity = new TestTableEntity 
{
    Data = data, //byte[]
    PartitionKey = partitionKey, //date
    RowKey = schemaName// string
};

await table.InsertOrUpdateAsync(entity);
```

At step of insert I get error

> The remote server returned an error: (413) The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit..

Cause array is really huge.

Is there any ways how to resolve this?

Comment: Chunk your uploads... possibly store them in the table as the chunks too so it is easier to retrieve them

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, any link how to do this? Something like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170921/3917754

Comment: Why not use blob storage instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Azure table storage, maximum storage capacity of entity is about 1 MB ([Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets)).
Check if data exceeds the specified limit, in that case you might need to store data in the [Azure Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and add reference to it in the table or directly using it.

Comment: Also, [the maximum size of a byte array column is only 64k](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model).